# Iterating over an array inside an if statement

Tags: java, arrays

I am building the game of life with customizable rules. I am receiving an array of numbers from a function and I need to iterate over the array in order to get a collection of numbers. I need those numbers to add to an if statement without knowing the length of the array in order to update the rules for the game of life. Here is the example for the code:

```
if(nAlive < 2)
  next[i][j] = false;
else if(nAlive == 2 || nAlive == 3)
  next[i][j] = true;
else
  next[i][j] = false;
```

What I need is (this is in pseudocode):

```
if(nAlive == surviving[0] || nAlive == surviving[1] || ... nAlive == surviving[n])
  next[i][j] = true;
else
  next[i][j] = false;
```

Comment: What you need... is already there. What are you asking us to do?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. why `nAlive[0] == 2` and not `nAlive[0] == 0`? What is `n`? What would be the check for nAlive[2] == ?

Comment: Just updated to clarify

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is:

```
if(alive[i][j])
                {
                    next[i][j] = false;
                    for (int x = 0; x < surviving.length; x++) {
                        if (surviving[x] == nAlive)
                            next[i][j] = true;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
next[i][j] = Arrays.stream(surviving).anyMatch(s == nAlive);
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is wrap this matrix by object in the next way:

```
public GameOfLife {
    private Collection<Collection<int>> alive;
    private int numberOfCorrectValues;

    public void addNewValue(int rowIdx, int colIdx, in value){
        if(isMakeTheRules(alive.get(rowIdx).get(colIdx)) and numberOfCorrectValues > 0) numberOfCorrectValues--;
        if((value) isMakeTheRules) numberOfCorrectValues++;
        setAliveWithNewValue(int rowIdx, int colIdx, in value);

    public boolean isTheMatrixMakeTheRules(){
        return numberOfCorrectValues > 0;
    }
}
```

when **setAliveWithNewValue** is change the value in the collection (you should impl it), and **isMakeTheRules** is method that check per one entry.

the idea is to save the state of the matrix every time and to calculate the big if only once and reduce the complexity from **O(n)** to **O(1)**